# getElementById() function is not returning expected value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

Why the javascript program is returing null?It should return objectHTMLunknwonelement

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mySignature()
{
document.write("samir imtiaz<br/>");
document.write("www.fb.com/samir.imtiaz37");
var k=document.getElementById("para2");
alert(k);
}
<script>
mySignature();
</script>
<h2> it is head 2</h2>
<p id="para1" onmousemove="effect()" onmouseout="effectback()">
this is my first paragraph
</p>
<p1 id="para2">it is paragraph </p1>
<button onclick="mySignature()"> my sign </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected output while tapping "my sign" button :objectHTMLunknwonelement

Output that i observed:null

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mySignature()
{
var k=document.getElementById("para2");
alert(k);
}
<script>
mySignature();
</script>
<h2> it is head 2</h2>
<p id="para1" onmousemove="effect()" onmouseout="effectback()">
  this is my first paragraph
</p>
<p1 id="para2">it is paragraph </p1>
<button onclick="mySignature()"> my sign </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected output while tapping "my sign" button :objectHTMLunknwonelement

Output that i observed:objectHTMlunknownelement

Comment: The function is called before `#para2` is defined in the `document`. You can use `load` event of `window` `<script>
onload = mySignature;
</script>`

Comment: `It should return objectHTMLunknwonelement` no. It will always return `null` if the element does not exist - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: The color highlighting in your post should also show you a big issue....

Comment: please format your markup.

Comment: Note also, `effect` and `effectback` functions are not defined at the code at Question

Comment: you have `<script>` inside a `<script>` block. now think again. in addition to that, you try to run `mySignature();` before `para2` actually exists in the dom.

Answer (score 1):

## Document.write()

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document.

You're replacing the document DOM before calling document.getElementById, therefore, the element `para2` doesn't exist.

```js
function mySignature() {
  var k = document.getElementById("para2");
  alert(k);
  
  document.write("samir imtiaz<br/>");
  document.write("www.fb.com/samir.imtiaz37");
  
}
```

```html
<h2> it is head 2</h2>
<p id="para1">
this is my first paragraph
</p>
<p1 id="para2">it is paragraph </p1>
<button onclick="mySignature()"> my sign </button>
```

Comment: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open, which will clear the document.    please explain these words in details,I am a newbie

Answer (score 0):

The first time the alert says `null` because the element doesn't exist when the code runs. It runs BEFORE the element is created. Once the page is loaded and you click the button the behavior for each example case is:

In the first example, the `document.write(..` lines in the method are replacing the dom with the elements you are writing, so the "p1" element is being overwritten and so the `getElementById` is returning null. Notice how the paragraph disappears after the alert.

In the second example, the object is not being overwritten, however it is an unknown tag type, so the output you observed is expected.